# How do I get the avatar URL instead of an HTML IMG tag when using get_avatar?

Tags: images, urls, avatar

I'm using a plugin called [Simple Local Avatars](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-local-avatars) which lets me upload author images which are stored on my server locally (no Gravatar). The plugin works fine and `get_avatar` returns the local avatar.

However, I need to use that avatar in different ways and different places and for that I need the local avatar image URL instead of the entire HTML tag. I could write a wrapper function for `get_avatar` that uses RegEx or SimpleXML to pick out and return only the URL, but I was wondering if there's any existing way to do this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Good news for WordPress versions 4.2+

Since version 4.2 the handy `get_avatar_url()` function, introduced as a *feature request* in ticket [#21195](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21195) few years ago, [now ships with the core](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.2-branch/wp-includes/link-template.php#L3414):

```
/**
 * Retrieve the avatar URL.
 *
 * @since 4.2.0
 *
 * @param mixed $id_or_email The Gravatar to retrieve a URL for. Accepts a user_id, gravatar md5 hash,
 *                           user email, WP_User object, WP_Post object, or comment object.
 * @param array $args {
 *     Optional. Arguments to return instead of the default arguments.
 *
 *     @type int    $size           Height and width of the avatar in pixels. Default 96.
 *     @type string $default        URL for the default image or a default type. Accepts '404' (return
 *                                  a 404 instead of a default image), 'retro' (8bit), 'monsterid' (monster),
 *                                  'wavatar' (cartoon face), 'indenticon' (the "quilt"), 'mystery', 'mm',
 *                                  or 'mysterman' (The Oyster Man), 'blank' (transparent GIF), or
 *                                  'gravatar_default' (the Gravatar logo). Default is the value of the
 *                                  'avatar_default' option, with a fallback of 'mystery'.
 *     @type bool   $force_default  Whether to always show the default image, never the Gravatar. Default false.
 *     @type string $rating         What rating to display avatars up to. Accepts 'G', 'PG', 'R', 'X', and are
 *                                  judged in that order. Default is the value of the 'avatar_rating' option.
 *     @type string $scheme         URL scheme to use. See set_url_scheme() for accepted values.
 *                                  Default null.
 *     @type array  $processed_args When the function returns, the value will be the processed/sanitized $args
 *                                  plus a "found_avatar" guess. Pass as a reference. Default null.
 * }
 * @return false|string The URL of the avatar we found, or false if we couldn't find an avatar.
 */
function get_avatar_url( $id_or_email, $args = null ) {
    $args = get_avatar_data( $id_or_email, $args );
    return $args['url'];
}
```

where [`get_avatar_data()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.2-branch/wp-includes/link-template.php#L3455) is also a new helper function.

It contains this code part:

```
... CUT ...

/**
 * Filter whether to retrieve the avatar URL early.
 *
 * Passing a non-null value in the 'url' member of the return array will
 * effectively short circuit get_avatar_data(), passing the value through
 * the {@see 'get_avatar_data'} filter and returning early.
 *
 * @since 4.2.0
 *
 * @param array             $args          Arguments passed to get_avatar_data(), after processing.
 * @param int|object|string $id_or_email   A user ID, email address, or comment object.
 */
$args = apply_filters( 'pre_get_avatar_data', $args, $id_or_email );
if ( isset( $args['url'] ) && ! is_null( $args['url'] ) ) {
    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/link-template.php */
    return apply_filters( 'get_avatar_data', $args, $id_or_email );
}

... CUT ...
```

where we can see that when the `url` parameter is set, the available filters are `pre_get_avatar_data` and `get_avatar_data`.

After upgrading to 4.2 recently, I had a problem with a theme that defined it's own version of `get_avatar_url()`, without any *function name prefixing* or a `function_exists()` check. So this is an example of why that's important ;-)

Answer (score 25):

The answer above seems comprehensive, but I just wrote a wrapper function and moved on. Here it is if you need it (put this in `functions.php`):

```
function get_avatar_url($get_avatar){
    preg_match("/src='(.*?)'/i", $get_avatar, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

and then use it wherver you need it in the template files like this:

```
<img src="<? echo get_avatar_url(get_avatar( $curauth->ID, 150 )); ?>" align="left" class="authorimage" />
```

It's just simpler.

Using RegEx to parse HTML in this case is okay, because this will only be parsing one `img` tag, so it won't be too costly.

Comment: A small change... the get_avatar function puts the src within " not ' so the match will be null.  The regex should be preg_match('/src="(.*?)"/i', $get_avatar, $matches);

Comment: thanks @spdaly - i hope commenting would make the author to edit ;) - thanks aalaap

Comment: If you answered your own question please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Darth_Vader I haven't gone back to this since I posted the question, so I'm no longer sure if this is the ideal way to do it. I think the new answer about 4.2+ is better.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the filter `get_avatar` for get all data to the avatar, also the url inside the markup. I think, WP don`t have an function for return only the url if the avatar image.

```
$avatar = "<img alt='{$safe_alt}' src='{$default}' class='avatar avatar-{$size} photo avatar-default' height='{$size}' width='{$size}' />";

apply_filters('get_avatar', $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt);
```

Also you can rewrite this function inside an plugin or theme, the function is onyl active, if this function name is not on other place defined.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_avatar' ) ) :
```

So it is possible to add an param for return only the url of the image, like this, use the param `$url` with `TRUE` and you get only the url.

```
/**
 * Retrieve the avatar for a user who provided a user ID or email address.
 *
 * @since 2.5
 * @param int|string|object $id_or_email A user ID,  email address, or comment object
 * @param int $size Size of the avatar image
 * @param string $default URL to a default image to use if no avatar is available
 * @param string $alt Alternate text to use in image tag. Defaults to blank
 * @param boolean $url, true for get only the url of the image, no markup
 * @return string <img> tag for the user's avatar
*/
function get_avatar( $id_or_email, $size = '96', $default = '', $alt = false, $url = FALSE ) {
    if ( ! get_option('show_avatars') )
        return false;

    if ( false === $alt)
        $safe_alt = '';
    else
        $safe_alt = esc_attr( $alt );

    if ( !is_numeric($size) )
        $size = '96';

    $email = '';
    if ( is_numeric($id_or_email) ) {
        $id = (int) $id_or_email;
        $user = get_userdata($id);
        if ( $user )
            $email = $user->user_email;
    } elseif ( is_object($id_or_email) ) {
        // No avatar for pingbacks or trackbacks
        $allowed_comment_types = apply_filters( 'get_avatar_comment_types', array( 'comment' ) );
        if ( ! empty( $id_or_email->comment_type ) && ! in_array( $id_or_email->comment_type, (array) $allowed_comment_types ) )
            return false;

        if ( !empty($id_or_email->user_id) ) {
            $id = (int) $id_or_email->user_id;
            $user = get_userdata($id);
            if ( $user)
                $email = $user->user_email;
        } elseif ( !empty($id_or_email->comment_author_email) ) {
            $email = $id_or_email->comment_author_email;
        }
    } else {
        $email = $id_or_email;
    }

    if ( empty($default) ) {
        $avatar_default = get_option('avatar_default');
        if ( empty($avatar_default) )
            $default = 'mystery';
        else
            $default = $avatar_default;
    }

    if ( !empty($email) )
        $email_hash = md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) );

    if ( is_ssl() ) {
        $host = 'https://secure.gravatar.com';
    } else {
        if ( !empty($email) )
            $host = sprintf( "http://%d.gravatar.com", ( hexdec( $email_hash[0] ) % 2 ) );
        else
            $host = 'http://0.gravatar.com';
    }

    if ( 'mystery' == $default )
        $default = "$host/avatar/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536?s={$size}"; // ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536 == md5('unknown@gravatar.com')
    elseif ( 'blank' == $default )
        $default = includes_url('images/blank.gif');
    elseif ( !empty($email) && 'gravatar_default' == $default )
        $default = '';
    elseif ( 'gravatar_default' == $default )
        $default = "$host/avatar/?s={$size}";
    elseif ( empty($email) )
        $default = "$host/avatar/?d=$default&amp;s={$size}";
    elseif ( strpos($default, 'http://') === 0 )
        $default = add_query_arg( 's', $size, $default );

    if ( !empty($email) ) {
        $out = "$host/avatar/";
        $out .= $email_hash;
        $out .= '?s='.$size;
        $out .= '&amp;d=' . urlencode( $default );

        $rating = get_option('avatar_rating');
        if ( !empty( $rating ) )
            $out .= "&amp;r={$rating}";

        if ( $url )
            $avatar = $out;
        else
            $avatar = "<img alt='{$safe_alt}' src='{$out}' class='avatar avatar-{$size} photo' height='{$size}' width='{$size}' />";
    } else {
        if ( $url )
            $avatar = $out;
        else
            $avatar = "<img alt='{$safe_alt}' src='{$default}' class='avatar avatar-{$size} photo avatar-default' height='{$size}' width='{$size}' />";
    }

    return apply_filters('get_avatar', $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt);
}
```

Another small variant is, that you create the url with the rule of Gravatar.

```
function get_gravatar_url( $email ) {

    $hash = md5( strtolower( trim ( $email ) ) );
    return 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/' . $hash;
}
```

use this on your source with the emails of authors and you get the url of there image.

Answer (score 2):

I think this a better version of aalaap's answer:

```
// In your template ...
$avatar_url = get_avatar_url ( get_the_author_meta('ID'), $size = '50' ); 

// Get src URL from avatar <img> tag (add to functions.php)
function get_avatar_url($author_id, $size){
    $get_avatar = get_avatar( $author_id, $size );
    preg_match("/src='(.*?)'/i", $get_avatar, $matches);
    return ( $matches[1] );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
get_user_meta($userId, 'simple_local_avatar');
```

[Simple Local Avatars](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-local-avatars/) uses meta fields to store the avatar, so you can simply retrieve the value(s) by calling [`get_user_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) and grabbing the 'simple_local_avatar' field. You'll get returned an array like so:

```
array
(
  [full] => 'http://...',
  [96] => 'http://...',
  [32] => 'http://...'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

alaap's method doesn't work anymore in Wordpress 4.2

I came up with a solution. Here it is and it's working good:

```
 function my_gravatar_url() { // Get user email
$user_email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' );
// Convert email into md5 hash and set image size to 80 px
$user_gravatar_url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . md5($user_email) . '?s=80';
echo $user_gravatar_url; }
```

in Template just use:

```
<?php my_gravatar_url() ?>
```

Notice: it must be used inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

When the avatar has been uploaded locally, WP, returns the img tag with the src attribute in double quotes, so I found this pattern worked better:

```
preg_match("/src=['\"](.*?)['\"]/i", $get_avatar, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

A few hours ago, I was wondering how to do that too. But, soon I got the solution and made a plugin, please check whether [get_avatar_url($user_id, $size)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/get-avatar-url/)
works for you or not. Thanks..

Plugin code:

```
/*
Plugin Name: Get Avatar URL
Plugin URI: https://github.com/faizan1041/get-avatar-url
Description: get_avatar returns image, get_avatar_url will give you the image src.
Author: Faizan Ali
Version: 1.0
Author URI: https://github.com/faizan1041/
License: GPL v2+
*/

function get_avatar_url($user_id, $size) {
    $avatar_url = get_avatar($user_id, $size);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($avatar_url);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)");
    return $src;
}


function sc_get_avatar_url( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'email' => '',
        'size' => 150
    ), $atts, 'avatar_url' );

    return get_avatar_url($atts['email'],$atts['size']);
}
add_shortcode( 'avatar_url', 'sc_get_avatar_url' );
```

**Usage:**

Calling the function:

```
get_avatar_url( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email'), 150);
```

Using Shortcode:

```
do_shortcode('[avatar_url email="' . get_the_author_meta( 'user_email') .'" size=150 ]' );
```