# Get only the author profile picture image url inside a loop

Tags: author, avatar

I need to get the post author profile picture link.

I know I can use `get_avatar();` but it displays whole image markup

```
<img src="http://.../img.png" class="avatar img-responsive" alt="image">
```

But need only the `src` of the author profile pic.

How can I got that ? Maybe we can use some `php` or `js` to take out the only `src` value from the total output.

My second question is, how can I add that `image` as `post_thumbnail` if no thumbnail exist for that post ?

Comment: Answer is here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188288/24875 You simply use the get_avatar_url() function.

Comment: Oh, I see it is a new feature, so I didn't got it in codex. Any comment on my second part of the question ?

Comment: in The loop you can check if thumbnail exist with function **has_post_thumbnail()**. In case of false display your image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the avatar URL instead of an HTML IMG tag when using get\_avatar?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59442/how-do-i-get-the-avatar-url-instead-of-an-html-img-tag-when-using-get-avatar)

Answer (score 9):

Putting the following inside loop should fulfill your needs:

```
<?php
$get_author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
$get_author_gravatar = get_avatar_url($get_author_id, array('size' => 450));

if(has_post_thumbnail()){
    the_post_thumbnail();
} else {
    echo '<img src="'.$get_author_gravatar.'" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

just use the function get_avatart_uri() and pass in the user's email as the parameter it will give you the avatar image url

Comment: I don't think `get_avatart_uri()` is an existing function name available with WordPress...

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar_url/, looks like a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Beside using `get_avatar_url`, you can still use `get_avatar`. If I'm not wrong, this is what you're looking for.

### Question 1

Get the post author profile picture link

---

```
<?php 
    // only output if gravatar function exists
    if (function_exists('get_avatar')) { ?>

    <?php
    // Convert email into md5 hash and set image size to 32px
    $gravatar = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . md5(strtolower($user_email)) . '&s=32';

    // Convert email into md5 hash and remove image size to use as post image
    $gravatar_bg = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . md5(strtolower($user_email)) . '';
    ?>
    <!-- Output the gravatar as img src -->
    <img src="<?php echo "$gravatar";?>" alt="">

    <!-- Output the gravatar as background url -->
    <div class="avatar" style="background: url(<?php echo $gravatar_bg ?>);" ></div>

<?php } ?>
```

### Question 2

Add that image as post_thumbnail if no thumbnail exist for that post

---

```
<?php
    // Check if post has thumbnail 
    // if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {            // option 1
    if ( '' != get_the_post_thumbnail() ) {     // option 2

    // if has, output the thumbnail
      the_post_thumbnail();

    } else {
     // if not, show the gravatar image
     echo '<img src="<?php echo "$gravatar";?>" alt="">';
    }
?>
```

Hope this helps, good luck!

---

*Resources: [Using Gravatars](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Gravatars) | [hast_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/)*

Comment: Hi, I know I can check `if(get_the_post_thumbnail())` and output that image in template. But that doesn't set the post_thumbnail, it only output on that particular template. I want it to `set_post_thumbnail`. How to do this ?

Comment: Based on your comment, I don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish here. Can you be more specific? You asked how to add that image as post_thumbnail if no thumbnail exist for that post, the code I posted does just that.

Answer (score 0):

> **UPDATE(22 May, 2021)** - *I am using a plugin [Simple Local Avatars](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-local-avatars/) to allow users to update images locally. The below
> solution will only work if you use this plugin.*

---

Just In case someone is looking for full image of author and not finding it. Here is a little hack.

### Simple Method

```
$avatar_url  = get_avatar_url( $author_id ); //this will give 96x96 image.
$final_url   = str_replace('-96x96.', '.',$author_avatar_url);
```

Replacing the `-96x96.` with just a `.`, Just need to make sure Image name doesn't include this string. Alternatively you can look for the same string from reverse and do the replace using `substr_replace()` like:

### More Accurate Method

```
$avatar_url  = get_avatar_url( $author_id ); //this will give 96x96 image.
$replace   = '-96x96.';
$pos = strpos($avatar_url, $replace, -(strlen($replace)+5)); // +5 for length of ext
$final_url = substr_replace($avatar_url, '.', $pos, strlen($replace));
```

---

*This is the first result on google while looking for full image of author so it might help someone.*

Comment: I don't think that would work for the default Gravatars: the size isn't in the URL like that, it's a `?s=` parameter. How do you have your avatars set up? Besides [get_avatar_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar_url/) has a documented 'size' parameter for the args array.

Comment: @Rup Sorry!!! You are right, I am using "Simple Local Avatars"(https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-local-avatars/) for allowing users to set their profile images locally and I think the plugin is allowing me to get a URL in the format I am getting. Completely forgot about this plugin. I'll add this plugin info in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

This is all I do to add the registered user's avatar.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_avatar_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>" class="YOUR CSS CLASS">
```